# Is restarting your router every hour to change it's IP address a good security practice?

Tags: router

Will it make it harder for an attacker to get control of your router?

Comment: I'd be surprised if your DHCP lease was that short, so even restarting your router every hour you will probably end up with the same IP address anyway.

Comment: It might help if your router is infected by non-persistent malware, then rebooting it might get rid of the infection. I'm not sure how common non-persistent rooter malware is though, compared to persistent one. As for changing the IP, that's totally useless, the whole internet is continually scanned by a lot of threat actors, all the time.

Comment: That would only work with a Dial-up Modem.

Comment: @user10216038 not true. Some ISPs issue new IPs with every modem/router reboot.

Answer (score 2):

No, it don't change anything.

An attacker will usually scan the entire IP range of your ISP. So no matter which IP you have, if someone attacks your ISP, you will be affected.

If you can access the administration interface of the router, you can change the default password, and configure the firewall to  block external access. Those two changes will make your router harder to hack.